# Accessing Nested Dict from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm using requests and JSON to pull some data from an API, and I'm struggling with using a nested dict.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{"data": [
    {
      "ContactId": "123",
      "EmailAddress": "abc@xyz.com",
      "FirstName": null,
      "LastName": null,
      "ClickDate": "6/6/1966",
      "Clicks": "5",
      "IPAddress": "1.1.1.1.1",
      "UserAgent": "IE8.0",
      "UniqueLinksClicked": [
        {
          "LinkURL": "http://link1.com",
          "LinkURL": "http://link2.com",
          "LinkURL": "http://link3.com"
        }
      ]
    }
]}
```

I'm able to access all of the ContactID and other 1st level stuff fine, but I can't figure out how to traverse the "LinkURL" stuff.

Here is my python...

```
result = requests.get(requesturl, headers=headers)
jdata = json.loads(result.content)
for result in jdata["data"]:
    contactID = str([(result["ContactId"])])
    for result in jdata["data"]["UniqueLinksClicked"]: #I'm doing this wrong, but I'm not sure how.
    print(ContactID + " " + str([(result["LinkURL"])]))
```

The line marked with a comment above generates a TypeError indicating it's a list, where I expected it to be a dict:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

If instead I drop the `["data"]` dereference and try to access `"UniqueLinksClicked"` on `jdata`:

```
for link in jdata["UniqueLinksClicked"]:
```

I get a key error because the `["UniqueLinksClicked"]` is an item inside of the `["data"]` dict.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: That JSON looks wrong. There's an object with three `LinkURL` values. Keys should be unique. Should this be three different objects instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the links in a nested loop. Do not use the same variable name `result` in two nested loops! Use a different variable name in the inner loop.

```
for link in result["UniqueLinksClicked"]: 
    print(ContactID, link["LinkURL"])
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've updated the post with the response.  It's expecting a string, do I have to expressly load it as another dict?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What happens when you tried this code? The code in your edit is not the same as in my answer. If you use `jdata` instead of `result`, it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me because I'm new. :)  Thanks for your help this got me to the answer.  I've included it above.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved from question.)

[OP] was confused about the variable naming in the `for variable1 in variable2["dict"]:` portion.   After some help from Håken Lid, [they] figured it out.

It should look like this...

```
for item in jdata["data"]:
    contactID = str([(item["ContactId"])])
    print(contactID)
    for link in item["UniqueLinksClicked"]:
        print(link["LinkURL"])
```